# How to run a cron job in ubuntu that looks for a new file in a particular directory and runs a script when a file is added to a directory

Tags: shell, cron, amazon-linux

I have a script to convert files, but each time i have to copy that script to the directory where my files are located and open a terminal and run that script every time i need to perform that action.
I have an idea of running a cron job to look after new files to a specific directory, and if any new file is added the script must start executing.

Help me out!
Thanks in advance

Comment: So, what is the question? If you need help running cron, read `man crontab` and `man 5 crontab`.

Comment: ohhk! i ll get back after finding ways with man crontab. thank you  :-)